# Acessar um textField que está dentro de um gridPane em javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Tenho estado a desenvolver um trabalho de mestrado em javafx: algo que recebe uma imagem, coloca uma grelha com textFields em todas as células por cima da imagem.

O utilizador depois pode colocar valores nos textFields. A grelha é criada automaticamente, dependendo do número de linhas e colunas que o utilizador pretender.

Esta é a minha class controller da view:

```
package vistas;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.print.DocFlavor.URL;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

import principal.main;

public class AreaProjectoController {

    @FXML
    private Button meuBotaoImagem, meuBotaoGrelha, btnLimpaGrelha, btnArea;

    @FXML
    private ImageView minhaImagem;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtGrelhaLeft, txtGrelhaRight;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane painelGrelha, painelArea;

    @FXML
    private GridPane painelCriaGrelha;

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    }

    public void mostraImagem(ActionEvent evento) throws FileNotFoundException {

        FileChooser imagemEscolhida = new FileChooser();

        // Define a extensão do ficheiro
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPEG/PNG", "*.jpeg", "*.png");
        imagemEscolhida.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

        // abre a janela para procurar uma imagem
        File ficheiro = imagemEscolhida.showOpenDialog(main.getPrimaryStage());

        // O if trata quando se cancela o carregamento de uma imagem
        if(ficheiro != null) {
            Image imagem = new Image(new FileInputStream(ficheiro));
            minhaImagem.setImage(imagem);
            painelGrelha.setVisible(true);
            txtGrelhaLeft.setText("0");
            txtGrelhaRight.setText("0");
        } 

    }

    public void criaGrelha(ActionEvent evento) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        int txtLeft = 0, txtRight = 0, i = 1, ii = 1, l = 0, j = 0;

        ColumnConstraints colunas = null; 
        RowConstraints linhas = null;

        txtLeft = Integer.parseInt(txtGrelhaLeft.getText());
        txtRight = Integer.parseInt(txtGrelhaRight.getText());

        //Este for cria a grelha após receber os valores
        for(i = 1; i <= txtLeft; i++) {
            colunas = new ColumnConstraints();
            colunas.setPercentWidth(25);
            painelCriaGrelha.getColumnConstraints().add(colunas);
        }

        for(ii = 1; ii <= txtRight; ii++) {
            linhas = new RowConstraints();
            linhas.setPercentHeight(25);
            painelCriaGrelha.getRowConstraints().add(linhas);
        }

        //Label fillLabel[][] = new Label[txtLeft][txtRight];
        TextField fillLabel[][] = new TextField[txtLeft][txtRight];

        for (l = 0; l < txtLeft; l++) {
            for (j = 0; j < txtRight; j++) {
                fillLabel[l][j] = new TextField();
                //fillLabel[l][j] = new Label();
                fillLabel[l][j].setText(String.valueOf(0));
                fillLabel[l][j].setBackground(null);
                painelCriaGrelha.add(fillLabel[l][j], l, j);


            }
        }

        /*for (l = 0; l < fillLabel.length; l++) {
            for (j = 0; j < fillLabel.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(fillLabel[l][j].getText());
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }*/

        painelCriaGrelha.setGridLinesVisible(true); //isto faz aparecer as linhas da grelha a preto
        painelArea.setVisible(true);



        //for(l = 1; l <= fillLabel.length; l++) {

        //System.out.println(l);
    //  }

        //Func.salvaInfoGrelha(listaElementosArea);

    }

    public void limpaGrelha(ActionEvent evento) {

        painelCriaGrelha.getColumnConstraints().clear();
        painelCriaGrelha.getRowConstraints().clear();
        txtGrelhaLeft.setText("0");
        txtGrelhaRight.setText("0");

    }

    public void defineArea(ActionEvent evento) {

        int txtLeft = 0, txtRight = 0;
        int l = 0, j = 0;

        txtLeft = Integer.parseInt(txtGrelhaLeft.getText());
        txtRight = Integer.parseInt(txtGrelhaRight.getText());


        TextField fillLabel[][] = new TextField[txtLeft][txtRight];// = new S[txtLeft][txtRight];
    //GridPane painel = new GridPane();

    System.out.println(txtLeft);
    System.out.println(txtRight);

    //TextField texto = fillLabel[1][1];

    painelCriaGrelha.getChildren().get(fillLabel[1][1].getText());
    System.out.println(painelCriaGrelha.getChildren().get(fillLabel[1][1]).getText());

        /*for (l = 0; l < txtLeft; l++) {
            for (j = 0; j < txtRight; j++) {
                System.out.println(painelCriaGrelha.getChildren().get(fillLabel[1][1]));
            }
        }*/

        //System.out.println(texto);

    }

}
```

A minha dúvida está na última função.
No fim do utilizador preencher as células e clicar no botão "defineArea" era suposto conseguir guardar os valores da grelha numa Array.
Tentei converter para Int, mas também não consegui.

Não consigo acessar o conteúdo dos textField da gridPane, talvez não estou construindo a minha função corretamente, mas acho que estou a pensar bem, quando tenho acessar com a linha:

```
painelCriaGrelha.getChildren().get(fillLabel[1][1]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o método `getChildren()` retorna um objeto tipo *Node*, vc deve perguntar se o `node` é de tipo `TextField`. Pode perguntar:

```
  if(node instanceof TextField)
```

e depois fazer o seguinte;

```
 ((TextField)painelCriaGrelha.getChildren().get(fillLabel[1][1])).getText();
```